# Problema com stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Estou tentando criar uma stored procedure que verifique se a tabela está ou não vazia, caso esteja vazia retorna -1, caso não esteja vazia retornar o elemento mais recente da tabela.

Estou tentando desta forma :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAVL_Ignition
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Value 
    FROM AVL_Ignition
    WHERE TimeStamp = (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) FROM AVL_Ignition)
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RETURN -1
END
```

Funciona normalmente quando a tabela esta preenchida, porém quando a tabela esta vazia ele não me sinaliza, no caso não retorna o '-1'. Oque esta errado ?

Comment: Como está a utilização da procedure?

Comment: @Sorack estou executando a procedure em uma query.

Comment: Então, tudo depende do jeito que você está chamando da procedure. Pra pegar o -1 você tem que atribuir em uma variável. Senão você precisa alterar o return para `SELECT -1`

Comment: @Sorack Eu utilizei o select ao invés de return e funcionou. Obrigado.